# Is it possible to import/run AML script into GRASS?

Tags: grass-gis, import, aml

I have an AML script that has instructions to import tmp files of (grid, network, basin...)
is there any way to run the script in GRASS? I tried to converted to Python but I couldn't do it for the whole script.

Comment: Could you please edit your question and post the code here?

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is 'no'.  AML (as the name 'Arc Macro Language' implies) is a proprietary language for ArcInfo and the calls within it are to ESRI-specific geoprocessing modules.  You would have to re-write it for GRASS to call GRASS modules either wrapped in Python or as a Bash shell script.  I'm sorry but I don't think there is any short-cut here which would allow you to simply import your AML automagically.